# Netlify deploy won't render css of hugo website

Tags: css, r, netlify, hugo

I'm currently making myself a website with the "Call Me Sam" hugo theme. Locally, the site works perfectly and displays as wished, but when I deploy it with Netlify the css styling seems to be completely ignored.

My repo: https://github.com/Silvestre15/Website
Website: https://silvestred.netlify.app/

I think it has to do with the linking of my stylesheet, either inside index.html or config.toml (or config.yaml). Excuse my ignorance, I'm a complete noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your browser console, you will see an error like this:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://silvestred.netlify.app/css/main.min.c5514d3530979d291f3497facc20da1cec870028dbc2a3630b64bab8721bbe49.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'Wfmg6q+vptwXAkTmYQmG/pnqYU1TL7/dWE1NGmPquyQ='. The resource has been blocked.

So your problem is the `integrity` attribute in your CSS link. If you remove this your site should appear correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I deleted the "integrity" part but it still won't work. Am I referencing the style.css file correctly?

Comment: I'm still seeing that attribute there when I "view source" on your site, and the same error message in the browser console.